# Texture paint stops working at shallow angle

Tags: texture-painting

Texture painting stops to work when the angle to the surface you are painting on is to shallow.

Shallow Angle:

[image]

Larger Angle
[image]

Can i deactivate this ?
Or decrease the angle, after that it doesn't work anymore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off Occlude and Cull and Normal and then you will not have a problem painting at any angle, but that may or may not be what you are after.
[image]